# excel formula to round off value on the higher side

Tags: excel, excel-formula

excel formula to round off value on the higher side

```
=ROUND(A1,0)
```

isn't working the way I want

Desired output

```
38.18 --> 39
26.22 --> 27
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method **CEILING**

for your query

```
= CEILING(A1,1)
```

will roundoff to next nearest number.

Ceiling takes arguments (number,significant)

Comment: does  ,1 round to the nearest digit or the nearest .1?  curious how similar it is to roundup.

Comment: The ceiling functions second argument is quite interesting an comes handy in certain scenario particularly pricing. The CEILING functions second argument can be considered as a MULTIPLE eg : (5.1,1) finds the next highest multiple of 1 which is nearest to 5 and multiple of 1 which is 6 eg2 .(5.1, 5) will roundd off to 10 as next nearest multiple that is greater than 5.1 is 10 [Excel docs] (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CEILING-function-0a5cd7c8-0720-4f0a-bd2c-c943e510899f)

Answer (score 0):

another option that does the same thing.

```
=ROUNDUP(A1,0)
```

A1 is the value you want to round
0 is the number of decimals places.  -1 will roundup to nearest 10, -2 to nearest 100, etc.  1 will roundup to the nearest 0.1, 2 to the nearest 0.01, etc